# Use of undeclared type 'WKNavigationDelegate'

Tags: swift, webview

I'm trying to make a web view to load an URL.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func loadButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

            webView.load(URLRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

It shows `Use of undeclared type 'WKNavigationDelegate'`. I can't find what's go wrong. How can I fix it? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I fix it.

I have to do `import WebKit` first